# Actionbar action button shown as drop down item instead of button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-button

Im trying to remove one of my action bar items(the settings menu) and add another one but its not adding the right icon/action to the action bar.

my layout file is as follows

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

and im initializing it like this

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

it shows the three android dots instead of my own icon(it also puts it in the dropdown
i want to change the dots in the red circle
[image]
what am i doing wrong

Comment: What do you want to change, actionbar icon or menu item icon?

Comment: i want to change the actionbar icon

Comment: You need to change the namespace, change `android:showAsAction` to `app:showAsAction`

Comment: Try my code also @Twizzler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your layout file should be like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Answer (score 0):

very easy ,Replace your layout code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```